# Should method go in class X or class Y?

Tags: oop

This is an opinion-based question, so chances are it will be deleted.

Let's say I have class `Teacher` and class `Course`. I want to create method `GetCourseId(TeacherId)` that will receive as input parameter a `TeacherId` and will return a `CourseId`.

Should this method be in class `Teacher` or class `Course`?

I guess my question is that if there's a method that can fall under any number of classes, where should it finally go? Is there some unspoken rule for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've often seen a third class created to handle something like this, where a method requires knowing about 2 classes and it doesn't *quite* fit in either.

In this case, it'd be the creation of a `CourseManager` that could contain methods like `GetCourseId`, `GetCourseByTeachers`, `AddCourse`, and other 'admin' tasks.

Many of these would serve as a wrapper of sorts -- `CourseManager.AddCourse` would likely pass a lot of work off on the `Course` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Normally i define classes like ***Teacher***, ***Course*** as java beans which just hold fields, getters/setters and some very basic methods which directly use the fields and don't include any business logic.

Based on the supported functionalities/features in my application, i create business/manager classes which implement my business through communicating with the other java beans.

So if i'm creating a simple course registration application for a university, I would define 3 java beans: ***Teacher***, ***Course***, ***Student*** in addition to some manager classes based on the features that i want to support in my application i.e. in our case ***RegistrationManager*** which would hold methods like: *registerStudentInCourse()*, *getStudentCourses(), addCourseTeacher()* ..

Please note that I'm just sharing my way of coding, people may or may not agree with it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution will be having a property like

```
private Course course
```

or

`private Set<Course> courses`

based on cardinality (OneToOne or OneToMany) in `Teacher` class. It could be ManyToMany as well depends on the requirement and data modeling. You can get or set course/s assigned to the teacher using getter/setter method.

Apart from this if the relation is **bidirectional** than you can have similar property in Course class. In case of bidirectional mapping you can have utility method like `registerCourse` in the `Teacher` class which will set proper relations between entities.

```
public boolean registerCourse(Course course){
    this.course = course;
    course.setTeacher(this);
}
```

You can have this kind of utility method in Course class as well.